# Detection of ethernet cable in Linksys router in Android application

Tags: android

Is there any way we can detect Ethernet cable has been plugged in or out in Android app programmatically.

I tried the following code
https://ufile.io/4d78x

Is it correct or need to change.

Please recommend if possible

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this by using the ConnectivityManager:

```
ConnectivityManager mConnManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

boolean isEthernetConnected = (mConnManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET);
```

You will need to add this permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html

Detailed explanation: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html#check-connection

Comment: Ok. I used that code, But the thing is that My Wifi has no internet.Its configured using Linksys router.

Comment: Wait, what do you actually need to check ? The code above will let you know if an ethernet connection is active. If you need to know the exact moment when there is a connection type change you can use a broadcast receiver (CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE).

Comment: @alem.Got your point.but the point is that the Wifi has no internet access.Its configured via Linksys router.The router is broadcasting the Wifi.I need to check programatically when ethernet cable has been plugged.In between have u implemented such type of functionality in android application.

Comment: Hey! To check programatically when there is any connection change you have to register a broadcast with the action "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE". Then in the onReceive method you can check if the ethernet is plugged (placing the code in my answer inside that method) and if there is internet connection as mentioned in the docs:
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html